# Reduced Residue Systems: $r_1+r_2+\dots+r_{\phi(m)} \equiv0 \pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_{\phi(m)}$ is a reduced residue system modulo $m$, and $m$ is odd, then $r_1+r_2+\dots+r_{\phi(m)} \equiv0 \pmod m$.

I am really confused as to where to even begin this problem or how to prove this

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $x$ is relatively prime to $m$, then so is $-x$. Now use a pairing argument.

**Remark:** We do not need $m$ to be odd, $m\gt 2$ is good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by a pairing argument?

Comment: For every $r_i$ in the list, there is a unique $j$ in the list such that $a_j\equiv -a_i\pmod{m}$. Moreover, $i\ne j$. So our collection of $\varphi(m)$ numbers can be divided into "couples" whose sum is $0$ modulo $m$.