# Sum of terms in a reduced residue system

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: Prove that if $r_1, r_2, ... r_{\phi(m)}$ is a reduced residue system modulo m, and m is odd, then $r_1 + r_2 + ... + r_{\phi(m)} \equiv 0\mod m$.

I know that $r_1 + r_{\phi(m)} \equiv 0$ because $r_{\phi(m)}=m-1$.

My intuition tells me that $r_2 + r_{\phi(m)-1}$ is also equivalent to 0 so on and so forth. I can also see that, since m is odd, the reduced residue system has an even number of elements. So each $r_i$ has a partner, namely $r_{\phi(m)-i+1}$

How do I show this rigorously?

Comment: in a reduced residue system, the numbers are not always {0,...,m-1} coprime to m. The RRS is only a subset of numbers which are coprime, are not congruent to each other and has $\phi(m)$ members, so i think assuming $r_{\phi(m)} = m - 1$ is not a valid assumption.

Comment: However if we restrict ourselves to a possible RRS, say {0,...,m-1} coprime to m, you can prove it rigorously as you are intuitively going, is there a way to generalise this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduced Residue Systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515067/reduced-residue-systems)